# Rspec - Elasticsearch automatic callbacks running in before(:all) but not in before(:each)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rspec

When I create a record in before(:all) in rspec, the index also gets created but it does not work in before(:each). Why is this happening?

For example:

I am using elasticsearch-model gem to trigger automatic callbacks.

If I do this,

```
describe "#update_company_indexes" do
  before(:all) do
    Company.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true
    FactoryGirl.create(:company)
  end
end
```

As soon as **FactoryGirl.create(:company)** gets executed, the index of company gets created.

But this same code dosen't work in before(:each).

Comment: Could you provide some code, please?

Comment: Hi llya, made changes to the question